# When the use sort an array, fix and write private static void sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

[image: Image1]

My Main Code is :

```
public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //////////////// Sorting Arrays
        String [] castNames = new String [6];
        castNames[0] = "Zareyee Merila";
        castNames[1] = "Hosseini Shahab";
        castNames[2] = "Bayat Sareh";
        castNames[3] = "Peyman Moadi";
        castNames[4] = "Hatami Leila";
        castNames[5] = "Farhadi Sarina";
        Arrays.sort(castNames);
        for (int number = 0 ; number < 6 ; number++) {
            System.out.println(number + " : " + castNames[number]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this line of code:

```
Arrays.sort(castNames);
```

Without having to write this one:

```
private static void sort(String[] castNames) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: Are you implementing your own `Arrays` class, or are you trying to use the existing one?

Comment: Try `java.util.Arrays.sort(castNames);`. Since your class name is `Array`, there seems to be some confusion (so you could also change your class name to something else like `ArrayTest`).

Comment: With this code, the problem was solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this question is a bit vague, but I expect you're just running into an issue with name collision.

You've named your class `Arrays`.  This class has no static method called `sort`.  There **is**, however, a utility in Java called `java.util.Arrays` which *does* implement a static `sort` method.

Your code is not calling the Java utility class, unless there's an import statement you haven't included.

Try changing the line to this: `java.util.Arrays.sort(castNames);`

Otherwise, you might consider renaming your `Arrays` class to something else.

Comment: Sorry my question was vague. When I use this code java.util.Arrays.sort(castNames); my code is fixed. Just do not know why when I added java.util.Arrays in line (1) The problem is not solved. I could related to the Java version?

Comment: No problem about the vagueness of the question :) I'm not quite sure what you mean about adding java.util.Arrays in line (1).  Did you add an import statement for the java.util.Arrays to try and resolve the issue?

Comment: @meygraph Even if you `import java.util.Arrays;`, your class is also named `Arrays`. The compiler is looking for a `sort` method in *your* class. Don't name your classes the same thing as standard library classes you're using, and you won't cause yourself grief.